# SKAction starting point

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction

How do you set the starting point for a SKAction? I am trying to animate a node in a circle, but I can't set the starting position. It always is set by default. Here is my code:

```
CGPathRef circle = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width/2-75,self.frame.size.height/2-75,150,150), NULL);
self.circlePathActionClockwise = [SKAction followPath:circle asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:5.0];
self.circlePathActionClockwise = [SKAction repeatActionForever:self.circlePathActionClockwise];

//[self.ball runAction:self.circlePathActionClockwise];
self.ball.speed = 1.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The starting point of the circle, when trying to move it, is based on the circles position. Try setting the position property like so:

```
circle.position = CGPointMake(100,100);
```

The above will set the position of the circle to 100,100.

CGPointMake takes the first number as the x axis coordinate and the second number as the y axis coordinate. I hope that helps.